# Is it possible to have 2 keys and 2 values in a single mapper script?

Tags: hadoop, mapper

I have a data set with the fields date, time, store, item, cost, payment. I want to find out the total sales/item and highest sale/store. Is it possible to have both the keys and values in one mapper script, if so can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create custom Data type.
This data type must be child of

```
WritableComparable<YourClass>
```